# Closest form.submit does AJAX query

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

Sorry for my english..

I have a button: 
    < a class="button" href="http://mysite.com/mvc3controller">< span>Submit< /span>< /a >

Submit

And a script on template page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submit-link").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to send form and display answer, but for some reason it does it with AJAX.
So, script gets right result and doesn't do anything more.

Comment: How do you know it does AJAX? Maybe it doesn't do anything? Show us the HTML code.

Comment: Not sure, but you didn't close the .click()'s function curly bracket, so you're probably getting a js error.

Comment: Radio: There is a network request, which i can see with FireBug. X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: eZakto: I mistaken while posting question here, in code its ok with brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't do AJAX. The .submit method simply triggers any subscribed events. If you have subscribed to it and AJAXified the form that might explain why an AJAX query is being sent. If you want to call the underlying event without calling any registered handlers you could call the native submit event on the DOM element and not jQuery's submit method:

```
$(this).closest("form").get(0).submit();
```